# Understanding Mindfulness through outwardly qualities

Tags: mindfulness, sati

Is absent-mindedness, the opposite of Mindfulness? If someone forgets to buy grocery on the way home despite having planned, does it necessarily mean he is very less mindful?

Do these qualities somehow affect each other?

More generally, Is there a way to notice in practical aspects of life how mindful someone is? If some one is sharp, is he necessarily mindful? If contemplative?

Does any out worldly character indicate mindful nature or the lack there of?

Comment: I see a lot of questions here. Could you try to sum it up into maybe 1 or 2 questions? Thank you.

Comment: The last sentence is the only 1 question. The other questions are more like a build up and description of the one question.

Comment: I see. I still think it looks confusing. If the other questions are a build up into the last question you should clealy state that in your question so that the reader knows what to answer specifically. That will also ensure that you get an answer you can use and not an answer to e.g. the first question.

Comment: There is only 1 truth. Within the 1 truth, all the other 3 truths are contained :) But all other truths also are truths, for elaboration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you asked this exact question on our monk radio broadcast last week. Here's the answer, for reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwDVIzD3O00

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Watching your Dhammapadha series of Youtube videos did bring in a great deal of peace inside of me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest for you the video; [Vigilance - The Heart of Buddhism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WayL9-OtG94&app=desktop), by Ven. Yuttadhammo. In here it is talked about mindfulness and the importance of it and also what charateristics a mindful person have. For example it is told why old monks still look radiant.

Lanka

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean about outward quality.So forgive me if I got it wrong.I think being mindful is not the same as remembering your groceries.I can be completely mindful of walking but as long as the thought of grocery doesn't arise I won't remember it.So its more about remembering to stay in the present moment.Also outward characters that shows mindfulness probably Introversion or quiet people since they are not scattering their attention through excessive talking.

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhism mindfullness is being mindful of the arising and passing of phenomena pertaining to the mind matter process, while being equanimous and comprehending the true nature of the phenomena and the process.

By practicing the 4 foundations of mindfullness this is what you try to achieve. Being mindless in daily activities doesn't matter. Being mindful devoid of the above in daily activities like a circus girl doing her act will not help achieve liberation.